# Form Object Gravity Forms

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

Gravity Forms.
I try to manipulate the form fields before they are rendered with

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render", "my_function", 10, 5);

function my_function($form){
...
$form["fields"][0]["content"] = 'This is a html-block'
}
```

Like this,  I can pass the html-block's content assumed the html is the first field on the form. 
How can I target a field by `id`? Let's say the above html-block-field has the field id `13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page about the form fields object](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Fields), it looks like you'd need to do something like this:

```
$my_id = '37';
foreach($form['fields'] as $field){
    if($field['id'] == $my_id){
        $field['content'] = 'This is a html-block';
    }
}
```

where `$my_id` is the id of the field you are targeting

Comment: If `$form["fields"]["37"]["content"]` does not work, your answer GhostToast will not work either, or am I wrong?

Comment: No. Because `'id'` is a real field. The way you mention `["37"]` indicates no assignment to a key. This is not a simple array.

Comment: Is there a way not to show gravity form if user doesn't have the capability?